# What does it mean the complexity of a polynomial function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am newly studying algorithmic complexity, big-o, omega notations etc.

I can understand such examples like nested for loops, for example. I calculate how many times the inner statement will be executed dependent on n, and that gives the complexity. For example

```
int a = 1;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){

    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
    a = a*2;
    }
}
```

I can understand that big-o for this above one is O(n^2). However, I also came across with this kind of questions,

> O( ) complexity of the function (n^3 + 7) / (n + 1)

At the first look, as an intuition, I want to think that as n goes to infinity, **n^3** is the dominant term in the numerator and **n** is the dominant term in the denominator. So, the complexity is O(n^3/n) = O(n^2). However, at the same amount it looks logical, it also does not. In short, I am not sure such a calculus-ish approach is correct or not.

**But more importantly**, I also do not understand what does complexity mean in case of a function. It looks like for any value of n, there is only a limited amount of operations will be done: Take the cube of the number n, add 7, divide by (n+1). So I don't understand how the complexity is affacted by n.

Comment: It backs to the definition of asymptotic analysis. Based on the `O` definition, the `limit` that you have done is correct.

Comment: i recommend to watch the first 30 minutes of [video from mit explain asymptotic notations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whjt_N9uYFI&list=PL8B24C31197EC371C&index=2&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare)

also i recommend to read chapter 3 from [Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844) which explain asymptotic notation

Comment: The complexity is of n -> infinity as you mentioned. It measures what the function approaches as n gets large

Comment: Do you want to find the O runtime of a function that has runtime `(n^3 + 7) / (n + 1)` or do you want to find the O runtime of calculating `(n^3 + 7) / (n + 1)`, as in the computational complexity of calculating this mathematical expression?

Comment: @SimonT it may be the case that I cannot understand it correctly, the original question text is : "Determine, showing your arguments briefly, tight bounds for the O( ) complexities of:
a. The function (n3 + 7) / (n + 1)". I cannot exactly understand which one of your two alternatives is asked.

Comment: Then I think you might actually be asked for the computational complexity of calculating this expression. For this you would use that n can be encoded in log(n) bits and then use the complexities of arithmetic functions (eg. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)).

Comment: @SimonT ok, thanks for your help, I will have a look at the link you provided

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question because you have spotted an ambiguity in the wording of the exercise you were given. The "O()-complexity of a function" is not well defined. You need to distinguish between the following:

1. The (e.g. time) complexity of an *implementation* of an algorithm in terms of O(...). Example: Quicksort with linked list.
2. The (e.g. time) complexity of an *algorithm* in terms of O(...). Example: Quicksort.
3. The (e.g. time) complexity of a *decision problem* in terms of O(...). Example: is a given list sorted?
4. The (e.g. time) complexity of a *function problem* in terms of O(...). Example: sort a given list.
5. An asymptotic upper bound on a *mathematical function* in terms of O(...). Example: upper bound on `(n^3 + 7) / (n + 1)`.

My guess is that 5. is the intended meaning, but the wording was misleading, or even arguably wrong. It *could* also be #4, but that mean: find an upper bound on the time complexity of *any possible* algorithm that could be used to compute the given polynomial, a rather unusual question to ask about polynomials.

Comment: Ok, my guess was also as your number 5. In such case can I say that it is O(n^2) with the limit to infinity kind of approach?

Comment: It's not a very precise and formal line of reasoning, but yes, O(n^2) is correct in that case.